# Why is there roughness on every surface?

Tags: surface-tension, fractals, fracture

Why is there roughness on every surface? I think a smooth surface could better minimize the surface energy. Besides, why does the roughness happen to be fractal?

Comment: What do you mean by roughness in your view?

Comment: Hi Haodong, welcome to Phys.SE.  Could you expand your question to include some examples of the 'roughness' you are referring to?  Also, can you quantify your claim that 'roughness happens to be fractal'?